# Can SID/STAR have shortened names?

Tags: fms, sid-star

I have a strange naming difference for a SID in a route. The route is:

> DOME4W DOMEG Y841 ANAVI DCT NVO UM170 KENUM UM615 IDOSA UN857 RESMI
>   UN491 DITAL UN872 DIDAK UZ15 ARDOD A5 VALAX VALA1A

I am bothered by the DOME4W departure ([Paderborn Lippstadt, EDLP](http://vau.aero/navdb/chart/EDLP.pdf)). The actual name is DOMEG 4W.

Is it allowed to have shortened SID names? In the FMS, I see this as well as DOME4W, but the SID description name it DOMEG 4W. Why this difference?

Comment: Which aircraft / FMS are you talking about?  Some FMS's may have a limit on the number of characters displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Jeppeson chart legend<sup>[pdf]</sup>](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/glossary-legends.pdf) those are *database identifiers.* I'm presuming that's what would show on a menu in the FMS.

[image]

Comment: See also the NATIONAL 7 departure from KDCA. Database ID is NATNL7 but the published name is longer.  "Yes" is exactly the correct answer here.

Comment: Great! This is awesome info... but.. I am not allowed to use this in filing a flightplan I would assume, but would have to use the full identifier?

Comment: It would probably depend on how you file the plan. If you file electronically I would presume the system would give you an error if it didn't recognize the format. If you're filing by voice I'd say the full id would be best.